# Conditional xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml of this format:
[image: XML]

What do we do to get the following condition :
select Batch value="xpkk" if manufacture date is wednesday, and select Batch value=abcd when the manufacture date is monday ?

Comment: What does your XPath look like so far?

Comment: I know its foolish, still something which i tried:- manufacture[@date="monday"]//Batch[@Value]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "manufacture date is wednesday" should exactly mean. But you may try:

```
//material[book/manufacture/@date = 'wednesday']/Batch
```

If your manufacture  where you are looking for is in a variable lets say `day` you may try:

```
//material[book/manufacture/@date = $day]/Batch
```